# Why is one of my columns not aligning correctly

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a table that I have aligned each aspect center middle but for some reason, one of my columns refuses to align. I've added the set up and output below. I have tried going into textbox properties and alignment it is horizontal center and vertical middle and I have tried deleting and remaking the table. Does anyone have any idea why this might be?

The SQL I use is

```
        SELECT 

         convert(date,format([rhStartTime],'dd/MM/yyyy'),103) as [Date]

        ,[rhAccountNo]
        ,Lower(Replace([rhOutcome], '_', ' ' )) as Outcome

        from [iPR].[dbo].[iResultsHeader]



    Where

  [rhStartTime] >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
         and [rhAccountNo] = @Client
```

I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the REPLACE or LOWER functions?

[image: Set Up]
[image: OutPut]

Comment: Are you sure there aren't spaces or returns after the visible text? Perhaps try a `TRIM` on it and remove CHAR(10) and CHAR(13).

Comment: Could also be a rendering issue with the browser, or the XML for the RDL file hasn't actually stored that the cells should be aligned centrally.  SSRS can render odd things at times.  Does look like a whitespace issue though.